# Express/Loopback/NodeJS is there a possibility to add an "index" to db field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, loopbackjs

we are using Express/Loopback Framework for our backend and what i am trying right now to assure that the indexes on some fields in models are created int he MongoDB. Is there a possibility to use some kind of meta-tags in models, on hand of which DataJuggler creates indexes in MongoDB?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the Mongodb connector here:  https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/blob/master/example/model.js

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the model definition JSON file here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Indexes

Answer (score 0):

As [M1kstur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420173/m1kstur) have  mentioned in the comments, you can [define indexes in the model definition JSON file](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#indexes):

```
"indexes": {
  "name_age_index": {
    "keys": {"name": 1, "age": -1}
  },
  "age_index": {"age": -1}
}
```

Also note that

> Indexes will not be automatically created for you, even with NoSQL
>   datasource connectors like MongoDB. You must run [automigrate](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html#auto-migrate)
>   or [autoupdate](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html#auto-update)
>   create your indexes!